# Focus? How to turn off when mouse moves

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I hope I am on the right track here? The website is at:

```
http://www.dinewine.com/startbootstrap-agency-1.0.6/index.html
```

When the mouse hover over the top navigation, the mouse-over background color is #fed136:

```
a:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover{
color: #555;
background-color: #fed136;
font-size: 12px;
```

Right now when I jump from "Reviews" to "Christy Lodge" the color #fed136 stays lit up on both "Reviews" and "Christy Lodge."

Is there a way to turn off the focus when the mouse leaves a link and goes to "Christy Lodge." I was thinking that maybe it is not turning off is because there is not a live url up on that soon to be link?

Any ideas are appreciated. Also, it is entirely possible that I do not know what I am talking about at all..

Comment: Just went to the site seems to work fine, link changes color on hover then back to original color when no longer hovered on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good tutorial on using CSS to change links: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

For unvisited:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
color: #FF0000;
}
```

For Hover:

```
/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
color: #FF00FF;
}
```

Comment: What I am seeing is that the yellow is not turning off on Reviews when I move to the Christy Lodge link?